# profiler to get the execution time for c++ functions in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, profiler

I am looking for a profiler to get the time spent at each function in `c++` code in `Xcode`, I have tried `Valgrind`, but I had problems with configuration because of `MacOS` version is `10.12.3` and it seems that it is not supported, I have `Xcode` version `8.2.1 (8C1002)`.
any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "in"? If somebody writes `printf("Hello World\n");` and the program does nothing else, running it takes a certain amount of time, like maybe 10ms. Is it "in" that program during that time?

Comment: well, yes, i would like to find out this 10 ms in a profiler that works for Xcode, without using (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

Comment: Then what you want is "inclusive" time. On a processor that runs at 1ghz, that's 10 million cycles, almost none of which are spent in that routine. You also want "wall clock" time, not "CPU time", because most of those 10^7 cycles are spent waiting for another process, or another process**or**, to actually do the I/O. [*Here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) is the method I and others use, when the point is not to get measurements but to find out what costs the most.